# Char count in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Input: AA1

The output will be:

```
Char  Count
A     2
1     1
```

Comment: Are we doing your homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495948/how-to-find-the-highest-consecutive-number-set-based-approach

Comment: Your example result doesn't seem to fit the data... Should it not be "C" instead of "c"? Why is there no "1" in the result, and if there should be one, would the count be two or three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier because it's simple count, rather that consective counts in your other question.

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Num smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @Numbers (Num)
SELECT TOP 12
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.NAME)
FROM
    sys.columns c1

DECLARE @STuff TABLE (Seq char(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT @STuff (Seq) VALUES ('12AABCCDDDDE')
INSERT @STuff (Seq) VALUES ('333345RRRR11')

SELECT
   Seq, Single, COUNT(*)
FROM
   @Numbers N
   CROSS APPLY 
   (SELECT Seq, SUBSTRING(Seq, Num, 1) AS Single FROM @Stuff) S
GROUP BY
   Seq, Single
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY
    Seq, Single
```